# Python basic error

Tags: python

I've just started learning Python. I have a little bit of experience with perl, and coming to terms with a language that seems to rely on indentations, and no termination characters.

I started small with code in Google python course:

```
import sys
def repeat(s, exclaim):
    result=s*3
    if exclaim:
        result=result+'!!!'
    return result
def main():
    print repeat('Yay', true)
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
C:\python>py repeat.py
  File "repeat.py", line 8
    print repeat('Yay', true)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Could anyone help me by telling me what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why are there two arguments in print function call?

Comment: As far as I can understand, there aren't. The two arguments are to the repeat function.

Comment: In python3 `print()` is valid not just `print` and use `True` not `true`

Comment: `print` is a bit weird in Python 2 and in Perl, but that's fixed when you upgrade to Python 3.  In Python 3 `print` is a *function*, which means you must supply the parentheses.  In Python the parentheses are mandatory for all function calls (unlike Perl and Ruby).  Also, In Python 2 `True` (not "true") is not a reserved word, but in Python 3 it is.